# Unexpected character "60" - Error trying to login to RTC java api

Tags: java, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I am trying to login to RTC java api 6.0.2 using:

```
TeamPlatform.startup();
repo = TeamPlatform.getTeamRepositoryService().getTeamRepository(repoUri);
repo.registerLoginHandler(new ILoginHandler2() {
   public ILoginInfo2 challenge(ITeamRepository repo) {
      return new UsernameAndPasswordLoginInfo(userId, password);
   }
});
repo.login(monitor);
```

but I'm getting the error below when executing the repo.login () method:

```
com.ibm.team.repository.common.TeamRepositoryException: Unexpected character 
   "60": line 3, column 1 
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.fetchClientVersionJSONObject(TeamRepository.java:1746)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.access$0(TeamRepository.java:1699)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository$5.run(TeamRepository.java:1770)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository$5.run(TeamRepository.java:1)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository$3.run(TeamRepository.java:1328)
at com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.CancelableCaller.call(CancelableCaller.java:79)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.callCancelableService(TeamRepository.java:1323)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.checkServerVersionMatches(TeamRepository.java:1773)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.internalLogin(TeamRepository.java:1521)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.login(TeamRepository.java:654)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.login(TeamRepository.java:628)
at snippets.Snippet1.login(Snippet1.java:67)
at snippets.AllSnippets.main(AllSnippets.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected character "60": line 3, column 1
at com.ibm.team.repository.common.json.internal.Tokenizer.next(Tokenizer.java:113)
at com.ibm.team.repository.common.json.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:30)
at com.ibm.team.repository.common.json.JSONObject.parse(JSONObject.java:72)
at com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.fetchClientVersionJSONObject(TeamRepository.java:1744)
... 12 more
```

This code was working normally, but suddenly came to give this error. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you are registering LoginHandler please user ITeamRepository.ILoginHandler as interface and do not use ILoginHandler2.

I can check snippets delivered together with RTC Plain Java API for more samples. Working code for 6.0.2 listed below.

```
public static ITeamRepository login(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws TeamRepositoryException {
    ITeamRepository repository = TeamPlatform.getTeamRepositoryService().getTeamRepository(REPOSITORY_ADDRESS);
    repository.registerLoginHandler(new ITeamRepository.ILoginHandler() {
        public ILoginInfo challenge(ITeamRepository repository) {
            return new ILoginInfo() {
                public String getUserId() {
                    return USER_AND_PASSWORD;
                }
                public String getPassword() {
                    return USER_AND_PASSWORD;                        
                }
            };
        }
    });
    monitor.subTask("Contacting " + repository.getRepositoryURI() + "...");
    repository.login(monitor);
    monitor.subTask("Connected");
    return repository;
}
```

Comment: I did this change, but this is not work for me. My RTC is 6.0.2

Comment: What URL do you use in your code? is it http://hostname:9443/jts? or something else.

Comment: I use hostname/ccm.

Remembering that my code worked perfectly and suddenly came to give this error. There was no update on the server

Comment: Do you have SSL enabled, is your certificate still valid?

Comment: Yes, it's valid until 2019